# Смещение значений во вложеных списках в конец заданное количество раз

Tags: python

Всем привет! Стоит задача смещать значения во вложенных списках в конец заданное количество раз:

```
def rotate_columns(x, number):
    s = 0
    for i in number:
        while s < x:
            i.append(i[0])
            del i[0]
            s += 1
        print(i)


rotate_columns(1, [[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: На выходе должнло получиться следующее. При х = 1 [2, 3, 1], [5, 6, 4], [8, 9, 7], при х = 2 [3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 5], [9, 7, 8] и т д

Comment: И что, нужный результат не получается? А если s обнулять в нужном месте?

Comment: Не получается. Мегяется только первый список

Comment: `Не получается` а как изменили код?

Comment: Нет в моем вареанте меняется только первый список

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in number:
      s = 0
```

решит проблему.

Можно ещё упростить:

```
def rotate_columns(x, number):
    for i in number:
        i = i[x:]+i[:x]
        print(i)
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Чувствовал что резшение где то рядом.

Comment: Вижу, что вы не приняли ни один ответ на свои вопросы. [Вот это читали?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)